# League of Legends - How to set hotkey mapping for default ctrl-click e.g. print frame rate to chat screen

Tags: league-of-legends

My [google search](https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&q=league%20of%20legends%20how%20to%20set%20hotkey%20mapping%20for%20default%20ctrl-click%20e.g.%20print%20frame%20rate%20to%20chat%20screen&oq=league%20of%20legends%20how%20to%20set%20hotkey%20mapping%20for%20default%20ctrl-click%20e.g.%20print%20frame%20rate%20to%20chat%20screen&gs_l=psy-ab.3...482751.521067.0.521338.87.70.1.0.0.0.1661.9935.0j27j11j2j1j8-1.42.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..44.13.2576...0j35i39k1j0i20k1j0i22i30k1j33i22i29i30k1j33i21k1j33i160k1.AW7dRVUVHyI) and [search on our site](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=league%20of%20legends%20how%20to%20set%20hotkey%20mapping%20for%20default%20ctrl-click%20e.g.%20print%20frame%20rate%20to%20chat%20screen) not helpful so I ask here; I also asked [on LoL board here](https://boards.oce.leagueoflegends.com/en/c/help-support-oce/Ni9FMzvn-add-a-title)

I accidentally set `Ctrl - left click` to another function and since then, I cannot print on-screen info e.g. print frame rate to chat screen.

I look in the hotkey mapping menu but find nowhere to set hotkey for that.
As you may know how to set it, please share.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried alt+leftclick?  Ctrl+leftclick is a "caution" ping by default.

Comment: I mapped Alt-click to other function too. Bad luck for me @@

Comment: If i'm not mistaking there should be a "Reset to default settings" key somewhere in the options

Comment: @AlexandreAudin Yeah, that will be my final choice since doing that will reset all my current key mapping.

Comment: @NamGVU But you know how to get back your current key ampping, what you don't know is how to get back 1 special key which is a default key.
It'll take some time, but reset your key ampping is the best way, after that try to find the file where it's stored and copy it somewhere safe

Comment: I agree @AlexandreAudin. The current solution seems to edit the config file and also going thru a custom game which is more tiring to follow

Comment: @AlexandreAudin Please add your solution as an answer. I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If i'm not mistaking there should be a "Reset to default settings" key somewhere in the options.
Once it's done change you settings to what it used to be and save a copy of the file in which this configuration is stored :

[image]

Comment: @NamGVU It's done !

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to assign functions keybinds through editing the `PersistedSettings.json` file.

If this solution does not work for you the keybinds might be manipulated through a 3rd party program and thus cannot be solved through changing settings in League alone.

From the **[Riot support center](https://support.riotgames.com/hc/en-us/articles/115005433708-Hotkeys-Keybindings-FAQ)**:

> Alternatively, there is a way to change hotkeys through the system
>   files. Since they are account-bound and saved on our servers, you will
>   need to perform certain steps in order to override the previous
>   hotkeys:
>
> - First, you’ll need to open League of Legends and log into the League
>     Client Update.
> - Afterwards, you’ll need to locate the correct folder,
>     by default, it will be in C:\Riot Games\League of Legends\Config:
>
> [image]
>
> - Once there, you will need to open PersistedSettings.json and find the “Input.ini” portion of the file:
>
> [image]
>
> - This is where you can make changes to the keybindings; once you’ve completed the changes, make sure to save PersistedSettings.json.
> - Lastly, you’ll need to join a Custom Game and exit. Once completed, your keybinding changes will be saved.

Answer (score -1):

I use `G + click` on element to show in chat the pinged element.
E.g. I press `G + click` on frame rate to print it on chat. I never used `Ctrl`, i'm used to `G`. The only problem is that if you want to ping something in the shop, you have to press `G`, then `P` to open the shop and than you can ping the wanted item.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: I just wanted to say that if he's used to `Ctrl - left click` for the function that he assigned this combination for, there are other ways to print pings into chat, so he does not have to change `Ctrl - left click`..